# how to fetch data from multiple table from single database

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

```
 i have three tables file, expense and payment. I want fetch data from 3 table based on foreign key.
```

I have following three table

**File Table**

```
FileId
FileNo
```

**Payment Table**

```
  Id
  Amount
  FK_FileID
```

**Expense Table**

```
  Id
  Amount
  FK_FileID
```

I want output like

```
FileNo      Amount  IsPayment
10001         220         True
10001         120         False
10001         150         True
```

**IsPayment is logical field** if amount is from payment table IsPayment should be true and if it is from expense table it should be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this query should do the trick:

```
SELECT ft.FileNo, pt.Amount, 'True' IsPayment
FROM FileTable ft
JOIN PaymentTable pt ON pt.FK_FileID = ft.FileId
UNION ALL
SELECT ft.FileNo, et.Amount, 'False' IsPayment
FROM FileTable ft
JOIN ExpenseTable et ON et.FK_FileID = ft.FileId
```